# Setting a non-standard proxy

Tags: proxy, http, redhat-enterprise-linux

I am behind a proxy which requires users to login during the first connection with a username and password with a HTML form. Thus, it is not handled with usual `http://username:password@proxy.com` and any attempt to access the internet from this setting falls into the login form.

How could I automatically login to the proxy? In linux, what manages proxy stuffs when a command tries to access the internet?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been successfully using `tinyproxy` so far to talk with the proxy by sending it a cookie it gives me when I log in. I then configure my clients to talk with `tinyproxy` (`export http_proxy=http://localhost:8080/`) and it works. See `upstream` and `AddCookie` options of `tinyproxy.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

If the HTML form doesn't have any JavaScript involved, you could send a HTTP POST request with wget (see --post-data option). You could stick a wget call to your ~/.bash_profile (if bash is your shell), so it gets executed everytime you login. The drawback is that you'll have a plain text password (the proxy password) in a config file.

Comment: Nice option but it does use javascrit :(

Comment: you could still log in using a browser, try to intercept HTTP requests, find the HTTP POST that's being sent to the proxy and try to craft it the same way